# How do I get around list aliasing in Python

Tags: python, list

This is really annoying. I create a sublist with elements from the original list. Then when I mutate the sublist the original list gets mutated too even though they SHOULD be in different objects in different memory locations.

```
data = [['male', 'weak'], ['female', 'weak'], ['female', 'strong']]
subdata = []
for i in data:
    if(i[1] == 'weak'):
        subdata.append(i)
subdata[0].pop(0)
print(subdata)
print(data)
```

Comment: `subdata.append([]+ i)` appends a new list reference joined with list `i`, so changes to subdata do not affect data.

Comment: You need to make a copy. Change line `subdata.append(i)` to `subdata.append(i[:])`

Answer (score 1):

Copying your sublist with `[:]` works:

```
data = [['male', 'weak'], ['female', 'weak'], ['female', 'strong']]
subdata = []
for i in data:
    if(i[1] == 'weak'):
        subdata.append(i[:])
subdata[0].pop(0)
print(subdata)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['weak'], ['female', 'weak']]
[['male', 'weak'], ['female', 'weak'], ['female', 'strong']]
```

Your original output:

```
['weak'], ['female', 'weak']]
[['weak'], ['female', 'weak'], ['female', 'strong']]
```

In case your sublist would contain a more deeply nested list use `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
data = [['male', 'weak'], ['female', 'weak'], ['female', 'strong']]
subdata = []
for i in data:
    if(i[1] == 'weak'):
        subdata.append(copy.deepcopy(i))
subdata[0].pop(0)
print(subdata)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['weak'], ['female', 'weak']]
[['male', 'weak'], ['female', 'weak'], ['female', 'strong']]
```